# MySQL - A procedure issue

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I've got 2 tables:

```
`deal` (`value`, `when`, `AccountTo`, `AccountFrom`, `Name`)

`account` (`AccountNumber`, `Value`)
```

I set up a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE transfer
(IN Value_IN float,
IN When_IN int(4),
IN AccountTo_IN varchar(26),
IN AccountFrom_IN varchar(26),
IN Name_IN varchar(30))
NOT DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''

INSERT INTO deal
(value, when, AccountTo, AccountFrom, Name)
VALUES (Value_IN, When_IN, AccountTo_IN, AccountFrom_IN, Name_IN);

UPDATE account SET Value=(Value+Value_IN) WHERE AccountNumber=AccountTo_IN;
UPDATE account SET Value=(Value-Value_IN) WHERE AccountNumber=AccountFrom_IN;
```

data is put into 'deal' but 'account' table is not updated

**EDIT:**

Thanks for answers. It works this way:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `transfer`( 
Value_IN FLOAT,
When_IN DATE,
AccountTo_IN VARCHAR(26),
AccountFrom_IN VARCHAR(26),
Name_IN VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO deal 
    (value, when, AccountTo, AccountFrom, Name)
    VALUES (value_IN, When_IN, AccountTo_IN, AccountFrom_IN, Name_IN);

    UPDATE account SET Value = Value+Value_IN) WHERE AccountNumber = AccountTo_IN;
    UPDATE account SET Value = Value-Value_IN) WHERE AccountNumber = AccountFrom_IN;

END;
```

Comment: Try surrounding account with backticks '`' in the last two lines. Not sure how to escape on SO, so no example. . .

Comment: I think you might need a `BEGIN` and an `END` before your `INSERT` and after your last `UPDATE`

Comment: +1 for `BEGIN` / `END`. Which DBMS are you using? Stored procedure syntax varies. I'm guessing MySQL, so you could try looking at the examples here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: All thats needed now is an answer to this question instead of an edit to the question itself... Ciaran? You did it. Time to shine. :)

Comment: @Ciarán, could you post the answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need a BEGIN and an END before your INSERT and after your last UPDATE. That's the case for many databases, - SQL/Server, MySQL, Sybase, Oracle all require a BEGIN/END.